# Sharepoint 2013 site public access with domain name Keep asking for Credentials

Tags: sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping, public-website, credentials

I have created a site in sharepoint 2013 and give public access to that sharepoint site with ssl certificate installed and server url like

> https://domain.com/sites/testsite/Pages/default.aspx

when I am accessing form public it keep asking for credentials even though if i enter the credentials again and again.

can any one help me.
I have added domain name to trusted sites in internet explorer but no use.

Answer (score 2):

> Here's is the solution to disable and stop the prompt for username and
>   password:
>
> - In Internet Explorer, go to 'Tools'
> - Click on 'Internet Options'
> - Open 'Security' tab, then click on "Trusted Sites" Zone
> - Add SharePoint Site's URL to the Trusted Sites zone. (Make sure you are adding FQDN of the site. E.g. Add: http://SharePoint.Crescent.com
>     rather "*.Crescent.com" )
> - Now,  Click on 'Custom level' button
> - Scroll down to bottom and select 'Automatic logon with current username and password'
> - Click OK.
>
> The next time you log on, select **"Remember my password"**.

**If still SharePoint repeatedly asks for Password than please try steps in below mentioned link**

[SharePoint Keeps Asking for Password Everytime?](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/04/sharepoint-keeps-asking-for-password.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply,
No luck Hardik
still it is asking for username and password

Comment: Have you tried other steps mentioned in given link?